# Opensource map webapp builder

Tags: open-source, web-apps, maps, gis

I need to propose an alternative exclusively built with free software and self-hosted, to an app generated with [ArcGis Web AppBuilder](https://doc.arcgis.com/es/web-appbuilder/).

The data to show are only statistical indicators (education, health...), at two levels of political division. There is no need to include advanced geo tools, the idea is more to navigate through a nice map and interface, see the details of the indicators for a given zone, download and print the maps, with the legend.

I'm evaluating the following options:

- [GisQuick](http://gisquick.org/)
- [GeoNode viewer](http://master.demo.geonode.org/maps/10/view)

Do you have better suggestions, or an opinion on these two alternatives?

Or would you recommend to build a custom web app, using libraries like [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) or [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) for the map and data part?

Note that I'm not asking here for the backend software to manage data and web services (it will be self-hosted, maybe with GeoNode, or GeoServer directly), only for a nice tool for building a webapp.

Thanks for your ideas or observations. If my message is off-topic, please tell me where I should post.